# A program to check if a number is present in series gives unexpected result

Tags: java

Program to check if a given number is present in an arithmetic progression series. User provides T, which is the number of a series that the user also provides.

User provides A, 1st number of series, B, the number to check if present in series and C, the common difference.

The code runs, but won't submit online(shows runtime error). Also, in each case the output is "YES".

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double n;
        int k;
        int T = sc.nextInt(); //number of times series will be given by user.
        while (T != 0) {
            T -= 1;
            int A = sc.nextInt(); //1st term of the AP series
            int B = sc.nextInt(); //to check if this number(B) appears in the series
            int C = sc.nextInt(); //common difference
            if (A == B) {
                System.out.print("YES");
            }
            n = (((B - A) / C) + 1); // if this formula is right then n should be 
            //an integer when B is present in series
            //or it n should be a float number if B is not in the series
            k = (int) n;
            if (k == n)
                System.out.println("YES");// even when B is NOT in series, "YES" is printed
            else
                System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java discards the remainder when dividing integers, so despite declaring `n` as a `double`, it will always have an integer value. You could replace `C` with `(1.0 * C)` to force floating-point division, or use the modulo operator `%` to sidestep the issue entirely.

Comment: You can also use `(double) C`.